# Bisection method

Tags: numerical-methods

I know how to use the Bisection Method to find the roots, however I have never used it to find the point of interconnection on two graphs. I looked it up and found that you can just subtract the two, such as y1 = y2, therefore y1 - y2 = 0.
However can I do this if I have one curved graph and one straight? I did try it at first but confused if I should deduct the line from the curve or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that either way. Because either way you get a function of subtraction in which you want to find the zero points. That is exactly what bisection would work. But make sure you can find an interval $[a,b]$ such that $f(a)f(b)<0$, if $f$ is the function of subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define f(x) pow(x,x)+(2*x)-6
void main()
{
    float x0,x1,x2,f0,f1,f2,e;
    system("cls");
    printf("Enter two initial starting roots:\n");
    scanf("%f%f",&x0,&x1);
    printf("Enter the tolerance value:\n");
    scanf("%f",&e);
    f0=f(x0);
    f1=f(x1);
    if (f0*f1>0.0)
    {
        printf("Initial starting roots are incorrect\n");
    }
else
{
    while ((fabs(x1-x0)/x1)>e)
    {
        x2=(x0+x1)/2.0;
        f2=f(x2);
        if(f0*f2>0.0)
           x0=x2;
        else
           x1=x2;
    }
    printf("\nOutput:\n\n");
    printf("Solution converges to a root.\n\n");
    printf("Root of the given equation is=%7.5f\n",x2);
}
getch();
}
```